# Serverless duplicates user pools instead of reusing by name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm using serverless to deploy an AWS CloudFormation template and some functions, here is a part of my serverless.yml file:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    MyUserPool: #An inline comment
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: "MyUserPool"
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy: 
            MinimumLength: 7
            RequireLowercase: false
            RequireNumbers: true
            RequireSymbols: false
            RequireUppercase: false
functions:
  preSignUp:
    handler: presignup.validate
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: "MyUserPool"
          trigger: PreSignUp
```

As you can see, both user pool names are the same, but when I run serverless deploy, 2 user pools with the same name are created.

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also found this to be counter-intuitive and confusing at first.  However, this *is* actually the expected (and documented) behavior.

When you attach a Cognito event to a function as a trigger, *Serverless* will create a user pool for you, without even being asked.  [Source:](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cognito-user-pool#simple-event-definition)

> This will create a Cognito User Pool with the specified name.

So in your case, one user pool is being created by the `cognitoUserPool` event, and the other is being created by your `Resources` section.  The one created by `Resources` is correct (has the custom password policy), and the one created by the lambda trigger has default configuration.  The fix is described under the ["Overriding a generated User Pool"](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cognito-user-pool#overriding-a-generated-user-pool) heading.

You prefix the User Pool key in the Resources section with `CognitoUserPool`, which will cause both your trigger and your resource to refer to the same User Pool in the generated CloudFormation template.

In your case, this means simply changing this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    MyUserPool:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
```

to this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    CognitoUserPoolMyUserPool:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
```

Tested with Serverless 1.26.0

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do this is by setting `existing: true` on your functions cognitoUserPool properties like so...

```
  createAuthChallenge:
    handler: services/auth/createAuthChallenge.handler
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: ${self:custom.stage}-user-pool
          trigger: CreateAuthChallenge
          existing: true
```

[Serverless added support](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/6362) for this in July 2019.